# Sqoop to create table schema using "sqoop create-hive-table"

Tags: mysql, hive, schema, sqoop

I have been using sqoop create-hive-table command with appropriate arguments which would copy the table schema from mysql or any RDBMS into hive. Today I came across an requirement where I had to use

"sqoop create-hive-table" along with --hive-partition-key  to create table schema with partition column specified. The sqoop command I used:

sqoop create-hive-table --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/XYZ \
--username XYZ --password password \
--table POC_XYZ_Partition \
--hive-table POC_XYZ.POC_Datatype_Mapping_Sodhi \
--hive-partition-key join_date \
--fields-terminated-by ',' --lines-terminated-by '\n'

which errored out with the error message:

`ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Partition key join_date cannot be a column to import.`

I know partition key should not be a part of create table command but I totally forgot that.

I then found a work-around and did:

`sqoop create-hive-table --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/XYZ \
--username XYZ --password password \
--table POC_XYZ_Partition \
--hive-table POC_XYZ.POC_Datatype_Mapping_Sodhi \
--hive-partition-key join_date_partition \
--fields-terminated-by ',' --lines-terminated-by '\n'`

The above created the schema but later when I tried to load data from mysql into hdfs it is considering the join_date_partition to be a part of mysql table and not getting the data from mysql.

I tried many solutions like:

`sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/XYZ \
--username XYZ --password password \ 
--query 'select a.*, a.join_date as join_date_partition from POC_XYZ_Partition a WHERE $CONDITIONS' \
--split-by id \
--hcatalog-database POC_XYZ \
--hcatalog-table POC_XYZ_Partition;`

but could not import data because of a bug in sqoop which would not allow me to duplicate the column names in sqoop.

Has anyone faced the issue and resolved it? If so, please suggest

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `-hive-partition-key` (and value) only does matter for uploading data into table but not for table creation. This also forces one to load only into a single partition at time.

But you could try to do your task in several steps:

1. Create a **partitioned_table**.
2. Load data by sqoop with `-create-hive-table` into plain hive **plain_table**.
3. Load data into partitioned table by using something like:

`INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE partitioned_table
PARTITION(partitionColumn)
SELECT col1, ... colN, partitionColumn 
FROM plain_table;`

Comment: Hive represents the partitioned column physically as Folders and put the data in the respective folders. The problem is not with loading  data into the table. The actual problem is to have the partition key also to be a value of the data along with the folders being created.

Also I think -create-hive-table would not load the data but just create the hive table schema. 

As we found out that this was a bug we went with a solution of having a different name for the partition key to have it as a part of data and also as a partition key.

Comment: partitions do contain values: folders are called like 'month=SEP' where 'month' is partition column name and 'SEP' is its value (at least it's true for hive 0.13).